# Android: Adding layout resource to library only for testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

In my common library code I am trying to create a inflater helper to manage multiple views in a ListView. This code is intended to be used in many projects.

I would like to write unit test for the following code for that I need some xml layout to be created. I know it is possible to have resources in Android library but I want that layout resource just for testing and not to be shipped along with it. Below is the code that I want to test.

```
public abstract class ListViewItemHolder {

    protected View itemView;

    public View getItemView() {
        return itemView;
    }

    public void initialize(View itemView) {
        this.itemView = itemView;
        copySubviews();
    }

    protected abstract void copySubviews();
}


public class ListViewItemInflater {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Class<ListViewItemHolder>>> viewHolders;

    public ListViewItemInflater(Context context) {
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.viewHolders = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Class<ListViewItemHolder>>>();
    }

    public <T extends ListViewItemHolder> void registerViewHolder(int resourceId, Class<T> viewHolderClass) {
        viewHolders.add(new Pair<Integer, Class<ListViewItemHolder>>(resourceId, (Class) viewHolderClass));
    }

    public <T extends ListViewItemHolder> T getViewHolder(View itemView, int index) {
        if (itemView == null) {
            Pair<Integer, Class<ListViewItemHolder>> viewInfo = viewHolders.get(index);
            itemView = inflater.inflate(viewInfo.first, null);
            try {
                T viewHolder = (T) viewInfo.second.newInstance();
                viewHolder.initialize(itemView);
                itemView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { /* TODO: Still to decide what to do here.  */ }
        }

        return (T) itemView.getTag();
    }
}
```

ListViewItemInflater registers multiple layout ids and view holder classes and on demand inflates the view for list item and populates the view holder class. I have tried to automate the view holder patterns for list item handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `shrinkResources` for this:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking